# Time stamp format

Tags: sql, db2, timestamp, datetime-format

I am having timestamp column data as a following format in my DB2 database 
111010124002

When i given select timestamp from tablename, i am getting time stamp as 101011230944. but my requirment is to get this in human readable format. such that it should e as follows
2011-10-10 12:40:02

Comment: Here is an article how to convert timestamps in dates: [DB2 Basics: fun with dates and times](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0211yip/0211yip3.html)

Comment: As a general principle, do not format your data in the sql server.  Instead, pass back the native data-type and convert it to a string in your client.

Answer (score 0):

```
select DATE([Your_Timestamp_Column])
from [Your_Table]
```

for completeness just re read the question

```
select DATE([Your_Timestamp_Column]), TIME([Your_Timestamp_Column])
from [Your_Table]
```